# Parametrized series - how to tackle this problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

We have the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{y^n+1}{5^n+n^5}$$

And the problem asks us to say for every $y\in\Bbb{R}$ whether the series is convergent or not (that is - we need to say for which $y$ the series is convergent, and for which $y$ it is divergent).

There are so many unknowns here for me - for example when $y<0$ this series turn into alternating series, also I don't know, even intuitevely, whether it's more of a $\sum \frac{y^n}{5^n}$ or $\sum \frac{1}{n^5}$ so if I were to use comparison test - I don't know whether to look for similair divergent series or rather a convergent one...

So, where should I start in order to approach the solution?

Comment: A necessary condition for the sum to converge is $|y|<5$ because otherwise the limit of the terms of the sum would not be $0$.

Comment: But what about $|y| >= 5$? Is this series always convergent then?

Comment: You mean if in the case $|y|<5$, the series is always convergent ? I think yes because for large $n$, we essentially have the term $\frac{y^n}{5^n}$ and this is a converging geometric series. For $|y|\ge 5$, as I mentioned, the series clearly diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about how fast the various expression grow.

The exponential $5^n$ grows much faster than the simple power $n^5$, so for large $n$ the denominator is approximately $5^n$. The numerator is bounded if $|y|\le 1$: in that case you can do a simple comparison test to see that the series is absolutely convergent:

$$\left|\frac{y^n+1}{5^n+n^5}\right|\le\frac2{5^n}\;,$$

and $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac2{5^n}$ certainly converges.

If $|y|>1$, the numerator is approximately $y^n$ for large $n$, and the fraction is approximately $\left(\frac{y}5\right)^n$. You know exactly for which values of $y$ the series $\sum_{n\ge 1}\left(\frac{y}5\right)^n$ converges, so you should try comparing your series with it. There are at least two possibilities.

- With a minor adjustment you can do a simple comparison like the one that I just did: compare $\sum_{n\ge 1}\left|\frac{y^n+1}{5^n+n^5}\right|$ with $\sum_{n\ge 1}2\left(\frac{y}5\right)^n$.
- Alternatively, just use the limit comparison test with $\sum_{n\ge 1}\left(\frac{y}5\right)^n$.